# Getting below exception is Testng but no error is showing in my project

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, testng

```
Default suite
Total tests run: 0, Failures: 0, Skips: 0
Configuration Failures: 1, Skips: 0
===============================================

[TestNG] No tests found. Nothing was run
Usage: <main class> [options] The XML suite files to run
  Options:
    -configfailurepolicy
      Configuration failure policy (skip or continue)
    -d
      Output directory
    -dataproviderthreadcount
      Number of threads to use when running data providers
    -excludegroups
      Comma-separated list of group names to  exclude
    -groups
      Comma-separated list of group names to be run
    -junit
      JUnit mode
      Default: false
    -listener
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing ITestListener 
      or ISuiteListener
    -methods
      Comma separated of test methods
      Default: []
    -methodselectors
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing IMethodSelector
    -mixed
      Mixed mode - autodetect the type of current test and run it with 
      appropriate runner
      Default: false
    -objectfactory
      List of .class files or list of class names implementing 
      ITestRunnerFactory 
    -parallel
      Parallel mode (methods, tests or classes)
      Possible Values: [tests, methods, classes, instances, none, true, false]
    -port
      The port
    -reporter
      Extended configuration for custom report listener
    -suitename
      Default name of test suite, if not specified in suite definition file or 
      source code
    -suitethreadpoolsize
      Size of the thread pool to use to run suites
      Default: 1
    -testclass
      The list of test classes
    -testjar
      A jar file containing the tests
    -testname
      Default name of test, if not specified in suitedefinition file or source 
      code 
    -testnames
      The list of test names to run
    -testrunfactory, -testRunFactory
      The factory used to create tests
    -threadcount
      Number of threads to use when running tests in parallel
    -usedefaultlisteners
      Whether to use the default listeners
      Default: true
    -log, -verbose
      Level of verbosity
    -xmlpathinjar
      The full path to the xml file inside the jar file (only valid if 
      -testjar was specified)
      Default: testng.xml
```

Comment: Can you please add more context ? 
1. What version of TestNG are you using ?
2. How are you running the tests. 
Please edit your question and add this information into it.

Comment: @manish Add some more information about your Project, there are multiple situations based on it this exception might occure. Information regarding, from where and how you are trying to run test file.

Comment: Its running as testng(Run as TestNG) only from maven project I have total 75 test cases(@Test methods). TestNG Maven Dependency Version: 6.3

Answer (score 0):

As I see it is an configuration issue. As You have not provided pom.xml details here I would like to point out few check points which would help you!

> 1. Add testng.xml to your project pointing to correct classes that needs to be executed.
> 2. Add pom.xml to project with accurate information described below.
> 3. In pom.xml file include maven-compiler-plugin.
> 4. In pom.xml file include maven-surefire-plugin.
> 5. In pom.xml under maven-surefire-plugin don't forget to add suitexmlfiles tag which will specify testng.xml file to be executed.

Thanks and regards,

Sandeep Jaju